# System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Invalid column name 'Email'

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, simplemembership

I'm working on a new ASP.Net MVC 4 app and testing user login. I am getting following exception:

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Invalid column name 'Email'
```

I'm using the example from http://kevin-junghans.blogspot.com/2013/02/adding-email-confirmation-to.html.

Here's the appropriate code:

```
[AllowAnonymous]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Register(RegisterModel model)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                // Attempt to register the user
                try
                {
                    string confirmationToken =
                        WebSecurity.CreateUserAndAccount(model.UserName, model.Password, new { Email = model.Email }, true);

                    System.Net.Mail.MailAddress from = new System.Net.Mail.MailAddress("noreply@cardmage.com");
                    System.Net.Mail.MailAddress[] to = new System.Net.Mail.MailAddress[1];
                    to[1] = new System.Net.Mail.MailAddress(model.Email);
                    System.Net.Mail.MailAddress[] cc = new System.Net.Mail.MailAddress[0];
                    System.Net.Mail.MailAddress[] bcc = new System.Net.Mail.MailAddress[0];
                    String Subject = "Please verify your e-mail address.";
                    String body = String.Format("Thank you for registering with CardMage." +
                        "To verify your account, please follow this link." +
                        "http://www.cardmage.co/Account/RegisterConfirmation/{0}", confirmationToken);
                    System.Net.NetworkCredential nc = new NetworkCredential("foo", "bar");
                    SendGrid sg = SendGrid.GetInstance(from, to, cc, bcc, Subject, body, "");
                    SMTP s = SMTP.GetInstance(nc);
                    s.Deliver(sg);
                    return RedirectToAction("RegisterStepTwo", "Account");
```

What am I doing wrong? I tried to find the solution from from the google search but no luck. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14912208/websecurity-createuserandaccount-propertyvalues) SO question that has the property values formatted the same way I do, so I checked my database, but the Email column does not exist. Can someone please point me in the right direction? Thank you for your time and consideration.

Comment: I assume you are getting the error on the call to CreateUserAndAccount and if you look in the database the Table UserProfile does not have an Email column.  Please provide the code for the definition of the UserProfile class, your database initializer, and the Global.asax Application_Start method. Note that this article assumes you followed the steps in the previous article on customizing and seeding SimpleMembership. http://kevin-junghans.blogspot.com/2013/01/seeding-customizing-aspnet-mvc.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get your email field updated by the call to CreateUserAndAccount, do the following:

1 Ensure the database table you are using has an email column.

2 Change the Account model UserProfile to include your email field.

3 Change the Register view to include your email.

4 Change the AccountController to include an anomymous object (this you have done)

Then, when you Register a new user, their email will be stored in the database table.

This works for me.

Comment: The columns are auto generated, how to garantee custom columns are created before "CreateUserAndAccount" call?